# c++ cannot convert derived class to base

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a very simple base class/ derived class scenario:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

       class BaseChannel{
          private:
          public:
           virtual ~BaseChannel(){};
           virtual void SayBoo( bool SelectAll)=0;
       };

       class gdbChannel: BaseChannel{
       public:
         void SayBoo(bool SelectAll) {if (SelectAll) cout<<"boo";}
       };

       class UsesChannel{
       public:
          BaseChannel * c;
       };


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   gdbChannel gc;
   UsesChannel uc;
   // uc.c = &gc; //cannot convert gdbChannel* to BaseChannel*
   uc.c = (BaseChannel*)&gc; // works
   uc.c->SayBoo(true);
   getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My initial implementation, commented out above, will not compile. Can anyone explain why? I feel that since gdbChannel is explicitly an instance of BaseChannel the cast shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because `gdbChannel` does not use `public` inheritance to derive from `BaseChannel` (the default for `class` types is `private`).

If public inheritance is what you wanted to express, just write:

```
class gdbChannel : public BaseChannel{
//                 ^^^^^^
public:
    void SayBoo(bool SelectAll) {if (SelectAll) cout<<"boo";}
};
```

Comment: wow, that was quick! This example was obviously derived, but I thought I had tried that in the main example. thanks @Andy